# How to remove subsections from mini table of contents using the minitoc package

Tags: minitoc

Currently my minitoc is showing all sections, subsections, subsubsections for a given chapter. I would like to only show the sections.

\minitoc

\section{Introduction}

\section{Second section}

\subsection{Second section subsection A}

I would like to remove the subsection, e.g. Second section subsection A from the minitoc. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Try using `\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}`

Comment: thanks! _______